# Does there exist a complex function that takes one complex number to another?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there any meaningful relationship between the values
$$z_1 = a \cos(x) + i b \sin(x), z_2 = b \cos(x) - i a \sin(x) $$
where $a,b,x$ are real numbers? Basically, $z_1$ lies on the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}  = 1$ while $z_2$ lies on the corresponding point of that ellipse turned 90 degrees. However, I don't know how to come up with a bijective function that turns $z_1$ in $z_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thre is no such relationship, at least not if $a, b, x$ are all allowed to vary simultaneously through all real values.

For example,
\begin{gather*}
\text{if } (a, b, x) = \left(1, 1, \frac{\pi}{4}\right), \text{ then } z_1 = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \text{ and } z_2 = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}, \text{ but} \\
\text{if } (a, b, x) = \left(1, -1, -\frac{\pi}{4}\right), \text{ then } z_1 = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \text{ and } z_2 = \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{gather*}
so there would have to be two different values of $z_2$ corresponding to the same value of $z_1$.

I'll see if I can add a counterexample where $a$ and $b$ are both strictly positive, which I imagine is what you had in mind.

I think this is OK:
\begin{gather*}
\text{if } (a, b, x) = \left(2, 1, \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right), \text{ then } z_1 = \frac{2+2i}{\sqrt{5}} \text{ and } z_2 = \frac{1-4i}{\sqrt{5}}, \text{ but} \\
\text{if } (a, b, x) = \left(1, 2, \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right), \text{ then } z_1 = \frac{2+2i}{\sqrt{5}} \text{ and } z_2 = \frac{4-i}{\sqrt{5}}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: Yes, I am indeed looking for $a,b$ both strictly positive (in order for the ellipse to exist). The only correspondence I found is that if you fix $a,b$ and set $f(x) = a \cos(x) + ib\sin(x)$, then the other value is $ -if(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was only struck by a bolt of common sense after I had posted!

Comment: The revised answer was accepted, but then unaccepted - have I made a mistake?

Comment: Sorry for that. After I accepted it I reloaded the page, which didn't show the answer as accepted, so I clicked the tick again, which must have unaccepted the answer...

Comment: Yes, I've often found the same thing: that when you reload a page, you get an older version of it. I'll never understand these new-fangled computer thingies. :)